# Как разбить массив на подмассивы?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть массив из 233 элементов: `[{},{},{},...,{}]`;

Как разбить такой массив на подмассивы, чтобы в каждом подмассиве было не более 100 элементов? (число элементов может меняться)

Например так:
`[ [0-99], [100-199], [200-232] ]`;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Одно из решений, через цикл:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; //массив, можно использовать массив объектов
let size = 3; //размер подмассива
let subarray = []; //массив в который будет выведен результат.
for (let i = 0; i <Math.ceil(array.length/size); i++){
    subarray[i] = array.slice((i*size), (i*size) + size);
}
console.log(subarray);
```

Answer (score 5):

Тоже поучаствую:

```js
const array = [], result = [], length = 100; // Объявляем переменные
for (let x = 1; x <= 233; x++) array.push(x); // Собираем массив
while(array.length) result.push(array.splice(0,length)); // Разбираем массив
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; 

const array_size = 3;

const sliced_array = [];

for (let i = 0; i <array.length; i += array_size) {
    sliced_array.push(array.slice(i, i + array_size));
}

console.log(sliced_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант

Разбивает массив на подмассивы размера SIZE

```js
const s = [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4},{a:5},{a:6}];
const SIZE = 4;

const res = s.reduce((p,c)=>{
  if(p[p.length-1].length == SIZE){
    p.push([]);
  }
  
  p[p.length-1].push(c);
  return p;
}, [[]]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```js
// Создаем массив из 233 элементов
var array = [];
for (var x = 1; x <= 233; x++) {
    array.push(x);
}

var subArray = [],
    subIndex = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Каждые 200 итераций меняем ключ для добавления в подмассив
    if (0 === i % 200) {
        subIndex++;
    }
    if (subArray[subIndex] === undefined) {
        subArray[subIndex] = [];
    }
    subArray[subIndex].push(array[i]);
}

console.log(subArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk) буквально сказано следующее:

> `_.chunk(array, [size=1])`
>
> Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of `size`. If
> array can't be split evenly, the final chunk will be the remaining
> elements.

Comment: а lodash при чем к вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

Короткий вариант:

```
const src = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

const result = [];
const count = 2;

for (let s = 0, e = count; s < src.length; s += count, e += count)
    result.push(src.slice(s, e));

console.log(result)
```

Можно завернуть всё это в функцию:

```
function unflat(src, count) {
    const result = [];
    for (let s = 0, e = count; s < src.length; s += count, e += count)
        result.push(src.slice(s, e));
    return result;
}

console.log(unflat([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в проекте есть lodash, можно использовать метод chunk

или следующею функцию

```js
const arrayToChank = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function chunk(arr, size) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(arr.length/size); i++) {
    result.push(arr.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size));
  }

  return result;
}


console.log(chunk(arrayToChank, 2));
```

Comment: ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b про lodash и ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732397/2659 про красивый slice. складываем и получаем новый ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно рекурсией.
Вот функция:

```
    const arraySplitter = (arr, qtyItems) => {
    let countItems = 0
    const lengthArr = arr.length
    const resultArr = []
    const splitter = (arr) => {
        if (countItems >= lengthArr) {
          return
          }
        resultArr.push(arr.slice(countItems, countItems + qtyItems))
        countItems = countItems + qtyItems
        splitter(arr)
         }
       splitter(arr)
       return resultArr
     }
```

arr - массив который нужно разбить

qtyItems - количество элементов в подмассивах нового массива.

Answer (score -1):

```
function subArrs(arr) {
    let result = [];
    const subArrQnty = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(arr.length));
    const qntEl = Math.ceil(arr.length / subArrQnty);
    for (let i = 0; i < subArrQnty; i++) {
        let tmpArr = [];
        tmpArr.push(arr.splice(0, qntEl))
        result.push(tmpArr);
    };
    return result;
};
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А кто такое просил?

Answer (score -1):

Самый лёгкий метод на свете:

```js
function f(length) { //параметр - длина подмассива
    let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] //любой массив
    for(let i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++){
        let subArr = a.splice(i, length)
        a.splice(i, 0, subArr)
    }
    return a
}
```

Если массив "не делится" на подмассивы нужной длины, то последний подмассив просто будет остатком, а остальные подмассивы будут нужной длины.
Например, если мы захотим разделить массив из 12 элементов на подмассивы по 5 элементов, то получим 2 массива по 5 элементов и 1 подмассив в 2 элемента.

Comment: Неэффективно, к тому же портит исходный массив.