# Как разбить итерации по пакетам в js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть следующий код:

```html
async function productProdIdStrategy(user) {
  if (user.fileUrl === undefined || user.fileUrl === '') return false;

  const access = {
    token: user.token,
    url: user.url
  };

  var newFileArr = [];
  
  try {
    const file = await getFileArr(user.fileUrl, user.id);

    // идёт перебор огромного массива
    file[0].data.forEach(field => {
      if (field.length !== 0) {
        
        //пушатся данные
        newFileArr.push(field);
      }
    });

    console.log(newFileArr)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```

В итоге на выходе получаем что-то типа

```html
[
  {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
  ...
  },
]
```

А нужно в ходе перебора (массив огромен, потому нужно сделать всё за 1 раз) массива разбивать его на части, что бы получилось что-то типа:

```html
[
  [
    {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }
  ], [
    {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }
  ], [
    {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }, {
      ...
    }
  ]
]
```

Помогите пожалуйста, что-то никак не могу додуматься как такое сделать правильно

Comment: если я правильно понял задачу: то я бы завел доп массив, в который бы пушил объекты, пока он не достигнет определенной длины. По достижении этой длины, доп.массив пушится в основной массив, а а сам он очищается.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732389/Как-разбить-массив-на-подмассивы - вот тут нашёл очень хорошее решение