# Разбиение массива, созданного методом serializeArray для динамических полей ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть динамически создаваемые поля ввода (input) для каждого товара:

```
наименование | количество | дней | сумма (вычисляется автоматически)
```

Для того, чтобы вывести в табличном порядке все позиции, я использую метод `.serializeArray()`. И потом его делю на подмассивы, чтобы все позиции не одной строкой отображались.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // этот кусок работает. Прикрепил для демо
  $(".dobav").on('click', function() {

    // ПЕРВОНАЧАЛЬНО КОЛИЧЕСТВО ДНЕЙ
    var InpDaysOne = $(".InpDaysOne").val();

    //получаем выбранный пункт селекта
    var nameOption = $('.mysel option:selected').text();

    //получаем цену выбранного пункт селекта
    var priceOption = $('.mysel option:selected').attr('data-price');
    // добавляем на страницу блок с заказом
    $('.contCals').append('<div class="dispNone"><div class="dopInp"><p class="ydalit"></p>' +
      '<p><label>Название услуги<br><input name="nameOpt" class="nameOboryd" pleceholder="" value="' + nameOption + ' " readonly /></label></p><p><label>Единиц<br><input name="edOpt" class="InpNum" type="number" min="1" value="1" pleceholder="" /></label></p>' +
      '<p><label>Дней<br><input name="days" type="number" class="InpDays" min="1" value="' + InpDaysOne + '" pleceholder="" /></label></p><p><label>Сумма<br><input name="sumOpt" pleceholder="" class="resoltSum" readonly /></label></p><input class="priceOption" type="hidden" value="' + priceOption + '"/></div></div>');
    //первоначальный расчет суммы чтобы не было пустоты сначало
    $('.InpNum, .InpDays').change();

  });
  
  
  
  // Кусок ниже не отображает значение. Т.е. не записывает результат в таблицу. 
  // undefined Выходит

  $(".info").on('click', function() {
    // создаю пустой массив
    var test = [];

    //собираю все инпуты, кроме скрытого. Он для расчета итоговой суммы
    test = $('.dopInp').find(':input:not(.priceOption)').serializeArray();
    var size = 4; //размер подмассива
    var subarray = []; //массив в который будет выведен результат.   
    //цикл делящий массив по 4 значения 
    // наименование - количество - дней - сумма
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(test.length / size); i++) {
      subarray[i] = test.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size);
    }

    // запись в строку таблицы позиций
    var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

    for (var i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      tr.innerHTML =
        '<td>' + subarray[i].nameOpt + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + subarray[i].edOpt + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + subarray[i].days + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + subarray[i].sumOpt + '</td>';

      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    //alert(subarray);

    //конец функции клика по кнопке
  });


  //удаляем строчку заказа
  $("div").on('click', '.ydalit', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });


  // КАЛЬКУЛЯЦИЯ ПОЛЕЙ
  $(document).on('change keyup', '.InpNum, .InpDays', function() {
    // получаем значения изменяемых полей
    var InpNum = Number($(this).parents(".dopInp").find(".InpNum").val());
    var InpDays = Number($(this).parents(".dopInp").find(".InpDays").val());
    //помещаем в переменную цену из скрытого инпута
    var price = Number($(this).parents(".dopInp").find(".priceOption").val());

    if (+InpDays == 1) {
      var price = price * 1;
    }

    if (+InpDays == 2) {
      var price = price + (price * 0.5);
    }

    if (InpDays == 3) {
      var price = price + (price * 0.5) + (price * 0.3);
    }

    if (InpDays >= 4 && InpDays <= 10) {
      var price = price + (price * 0.5) + (price * 0.3) + ((price * 0.15) * (InpDays - 3));
    }

    if (InpDays > 10) {
      var price = price + (price * 0.5) + (price * 0.3) + ((price * 0.15) * 7) + ((price * 0.10) * (InpDays - 10));
    }
    // Поле сумма
    $(this).parents(".dopInp").find(".resoltSum").val(+InpNum * +price + " ₽");
  });
});
```

```css
.dd {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

.dopInp p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: green;
}

.dopInp input,
select,
.InpDaysOne {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.dopInp input[type=number] {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 50px;
}

.dobav,
.info {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 0px solid #252525;
  outline: none;
  background: #56ef8c;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dispNone {
  display: ;
}

.ydalit {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: red;
  /*background: url(1200px-Multiplica.png) no-repeat center;*/
  background-size: contain;
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.ydalit:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.nameOboryd {
  width: 250px;
}

table {
  border: 0px solid gray;
  width: 80%;
}

td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label>Количество дней <br><input pleceholder="" type="number" min="1" value="1" class="InpDaysOne"  /></label></p>
<select class="mysel chosen-select">
  <optgroup label="Группа 2">
    <option data-price="7000">Товар 1</option>
    <option data-price="2500">Товар 2</option>
    <option data-price="2500">Товар 3</option>
  <optgroup label="Группа 2">
    <option data-price="1000">Товар 4</option>
   <optgroup label="Группа 3">
     <option data-price="500">Товар 5</option>
     <option data-price="5000">Товар 6</option>
     <option data-price="2500">Товар 7</option>
</select>

<button class="dobav">добавить</button>

<div class="contCals"></div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="tableResolt">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Оборудование</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button class="info">Рассчитать</button>
```

Проблема в том, что значение перебираемого объекта не выводится: получается либо `undefined`, либо `[object object]`.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/732389/256824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если по минимуму менять ваш код, то будет лучше, если добавлять в массив товар с явным прописыванием свойств товара:

```
// цикл делящий массив по 4 значения
// наименование - количество - дней - сумма
for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(test.length / size); i++) {
  var values = test.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size);

  // Получается вот такой массив объектов для одного товара:
  // console.log(values);
  // [
  //   0: {name: "nameOpt", value: "Товар 1 "}
  //   1: {name: "edOpt", value: "1"}
  //   2: {name: "days", value: "1"}
  //   3: {name: "sumOpt", value: "7000 ₽"}
  // ]

  subarray.push({
    nameOpt: values[0].value,
    edOpt: values[1].value,
    days: values[2].value,
    sumOpt: values[3].value
  })
}
```

---

Еще лучше, если таблицу тут же заполнять без дублирующего перебора:

```
$('.info').on('click', function() {
  // Собираю все инпуты, кроме скрытого. Он для расчета итоговой суммы.
  var test = $('.dopInp').find(':input:not(.priceOption)').serializeArray();

  // Размер подмассива.
  var size = 4;

  // Количество товаров.
  var count = Math.ceil(test.length / size);

  // Выбираем тело таблицы, к которой будут добавлены товары.
  var tbody = $('tbody');

  // Цикл, делящий массив на массивы по 4 значения:
  // наименование - количество - дней - сумма.
  // Каждый товар - это массив из 4 объектов (характеристик товара).
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var values = test.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size);

    tbody.append(
      $('<tr />').html(
        '<td>' + values[0].value + '</td>' + // наименование
        '<td>' + values[1].value + '</td>' + // количество
        '<td>' + values[2].value + '</td>' + // дней
        '<td>' + values[3].value + '</td>' // сумма
      )
    );
  }
});
```