# Разделить массив на чанки

Tags: javascript

Изначальная задача : Разбить на чанки массив
Пример правильного выполнения кода: `[9342,259,358,452,4292,57] ===>>> [[9342,259,358],[452,4292,57]]`

```js
let array1 = [9342, 259, 358, 452, 4292, 57, 7, 8, 9];
let array0 = array1;
let suport = [];
let x = [];
let k = 0;
let i = 0;
for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    suport[i] = array0.shift();
  }

  x[k] = suport;
  console.log(x[k], "<---------");
  console.log(suport, "<=============");
}
console.log("-----------------------------------");
console.log(x[0]);
console.log(x[1]);
console.log(x[2]);
console.log(x);
```

Не могу понять почему в ячейках x[0] , x[1] , x[2] во время цикла одно значение, а когда цикл заканчивается, первые две ячейки принимают значение последней(x[2]).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разбить массив на подмассивы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b)

Comment: вот шикарное решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b/732434#732434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда создается массив (также объект, функция) — выделяется конкретный адрес в памяти, через который можно получить доступ к массиву. Операция присваивания не создает новый массив, а лишь копирует адрес (ссылку на массив) в переменную. Несколько переменных могут ссылаться на один и тот же массив, и менять его значения.

Демо:

```js
let a = [0, 0, 0];
let b = a;
let c = a;

b[0] = 10;
c[1] = 50;

console.log( a ); // [10, 50, 0]
// a, b, c — ссылки на один массив.
```

Ошибки в коде:

```
let array1 = [9342, 259, 358, 452, 4292, 57, 7, 8, 9];
let array0 = array1; // <---(1.1) всё равно в итоге работаем с array1
let suport = []; // <---(2.1)
let x = [];
let k = 0;
let i = 0;
for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    suport[i] = (array0.shift()); // <---(1.2) удаляются элементы array1
  }
  x[k] = suport; // <---(2.2)
  // x[0], x[1], x[2] ссылаются на тот же массив support
}
```

Лечение: На каждой итерации создавать новый массив.

```js
let array = [9342, 259, 358, 452, 4292, 57, 7, 8, 9, 0];

let x = [], size = 3;

for (let k = 0; k < array.length / size; k++) {
  let chunk = []; // <---
  
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let index = k * size + i; // <--- Фокус) shift() не нужен. 
    if (index >= array.length) break; // элементы закончились.
    
    chunk[i] = array[index];
  }
  
  x[k] = chunk;
}

console.log( x );
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important }
```

`let chunk = [];` — Можно сразу заменить на `x[k] = [];` ... `x[k][i] = array[index];`

---

P.s. Если действительно надо будет создать новый массив с такими же значениями, а не просто копировать ссылку, `let arr2 = arr1.slice(0);` или `let arr2 = [...arr1]`

Comment: Во, ответ по делу, +1)

Answer (score 2):

Задачу разбития массива на группы можно выполнить следующим простым образом:

```js
let input = [9342,259,358,452,4292,57,7,8,9], // Ваш массив
    size = 3, // Длина "чанка"
    output = []; // результат

// Выполняем цикл : (длина массива / длина чанка) = кол-во шагов
for(let i = 0; i < (input.length / size); i++) {
  output[i] = input.slice(i*size, i*size+size);
  // Добавляем новое значение в исх.массив, которое равно - часть массива из входящего массива от i*size (текущая) позиции до текущая + size, это будет массив.
}

console.info(output);
```